# space must not be replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario,in textarea when I selected some text,the text must be replaced with stars.

Javascript:

```
    function getSel() {
    // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    // obtain the index of the first selected character
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    // obtain the index of the last selected character
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    //obtain all Text
    var allText = txtarea.value;

    // obtain the selected text
    var sel = Array(finish - start).join("*");
    //append te text;
    var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
    txtarea.value = newText;

    $('#newpost').offset({ top: 0, left: 0 }).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var position;
    $('#newpost').hide();
    $('#mytextarea').on('select', function (e) {
        $('#newpost').offset(position).show();
        var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
        var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
        var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
        $('#newpost p').text(Array(finish - start).join("*"));
    }).on('mousedown', function (e) {
        position = { top: e.pageY-5, left: e.pageX };
    });
    $('#newpost').hide();
     });
```

Here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/J8vwEwM7jhOBS9q6tpdM?p=preview)

Here the space must not be replaced and I am facing problem in getting  count of text(i.e some times text count different from starts count).After replacing, again the replaced stars must not be replaced when selected.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `Array(finish - start).join("*")` e.g. only 4 stars going to be used for joining 5 elements. You need to use `Array(finish - start + 1).join("*")`

Comment: @RonyLoud here spaces must be remain as same after replacing..can you please help me in this

Comment: May it help [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WJRqlvi1KZ6NckwlL8vc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Here's is the solution to you query :

Selected text's count is incorrect due to the event called on click. So before you select text click event fired. and whatever selected text count at that time, it will return that number.

Solution: Use Mouse Up Event handler instead of click

```
$("#mytextarea").mouseup(function() {
  // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
  // obtain the index of the first selected character
  var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
  // obtain the index of the last selected character
 var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
  //obtain all Text
  var allText = txtarea.value;

  // obtain the selected text
  var sel = Array(finish - start).join("*");
  //append te text;
  var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + sel + 
allText.substring(finish, allText.length);
  txtarea.value = newText;

  $('#newpost').offset({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getSel() {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
  var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
  var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
  //obtain all Text
  var allText = txtarea.value;
  var ltext = allText;
  // obtain the selected text
  for (var i = start; i < finish; i++) {
    if (allText.charAt(i) != " ") {
      ltext = replaceAt(ltext, i, "*");
    }
  }

  txtarea.value = ltext;

  $('#newpost').offset({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  }).hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var position;
  $('#newpost').hide();
  $('#mytextarea').on('select', function(e) {
    $('#newpost').offset(position).show();
    var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
    var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
    var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
    $('#newpost p').text(Array(finish - start).join("*"));
  }).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    position = {
      top: e.pageY - 5,
      left: e.pageX
    };
  });
  $('#newpost').hide();
});

// replace the 'n'th character of 's' with 't'
function replaceAt(s, n, t) {
  return s.substring(0, n) + t + s.substring(n + 1);
}
```

```css
#mytextarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden
}

#newpost {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
}

input:button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textArea id="mytextarea"></textArea>
     <input type="button" onclick="getSel()" value="click"/>
    <div id="newpost">
        
    </div>
```